# PHP script doesn't fully load in browser

Tags: php

I have a lengthy PHP script that is not fully loading for certain folks. You can see some examples of the problem in the following screenshots:

**Screenshot 1**:

[image: Screenshot 1]

**Screenshot 2**:

[image: Screenshot 2]

**Screenshot 3**:

[image: Screenshot 3]

No matter what I do, I cannot replicate this issue on my system or any other systems. I've asked co-workers to try, but the script fully loads for them as expected. I've tried Windows and Mac systems. I've used the same browser (Firefox) version that the folks who get this issue are using. I've had these people clear cache, clear cookies, restart their browser, restart their computer, etc, but nothing is working.

I implemented what I thought would fix the issue by changing all of the PHP echo statements used to display HTML (there are hundreds) to standard HTML, and then only outputting the PHP variable using printf. For example, I changed the following code:

```
<tr>
    <td class="cell_grey_background">Air / Hydraulic Systems, etc. for Leakage <?php if (isset($air_hydraulic_systems_for_leakage_error)) echo "<span class='red_text'>$required_field_error</span>"; ?></td>
    <td class="border_only" align="center"><?php echo "<input id='air_hydraulic_systems_leakage_pass' class='inspection-radio-btn' name='air_hydraulic_systems_leakage' type='radio' value='1' $air_hydraulic_systems_for_leakage_pass_checked $disable_field />"; ?></td>
    <td class="border_only" align="center"><?php echo "<input id='air_hydraulic_systems_leakage_fail' class='inspection-radio-btn' name='air_hydraulic_systems_leakage' type='radio' value='2' $air_hydraulic_systems_for_leakage_fail_checked $disable_field />"; ?></td>
    <td class="border_only" align="center"><?php echo "<input id='air_hydraulic_systems_leakage_na' class='inspection-radio-btn' name='air_hydraulic_systems_leakage' type='radio' value='9' $air_hydraulic_systems_for_leakage_NA_checked $disable_field />"; ?></td>
</tr>
```

To this instead:

```
<tr>
    <td class="cell_grey_background">Hydraulic Systems for Leakage <?php if (isset($hydraulic_systems_for_leakage_error)) echo "<span class='red_text'>$required_field_error</span>"; ?></td>
    <td class="border_only" align="center">
        <input id='hydraulic_systems_for_leakage_pass' class='inspection-radio-btn' name='hydraulic_systems_for_leakage' type='radio' value='1' <?php if ($hydraulic_systems_for_leakage_pass_checked) { printf($hydraulic_systems_for_leakage_pass_checked); } ?> <?php printf($disable_field); ?> />
    </td>
    <td class="border_only" align="center">
        <input id='hydraulic_systems_for_leakage_fail' class='inspection-radio-btn' name='hydraulic_systems_for_leakage' type='radio' value='2' <?php if ($hydraulic_systems_for_leakage_fail_checked) { printf($hydraulic_systems_for_leakage_fail_checked); } ?> <?php printf($disable_field); ?> />
    </td>
    <td class="border_only" align="center">
        <input id='hydraulic_systems_for_leakage_na' class='inspection-radio-btn' name='hydraulic_systems_for_leakage' type='radio' value='9' <?php if ($hydraulic_systems_for_leakage_NA_checked) { printf($hydraulic_systems_for_leakage_NA_checked); } ?> <?php printf($disable_field); ?> />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I did this for each and every row in every table on the page (there are hundreds as it is a long script). After I made this changed and pushed the code to production, the user said that the problem was fixed. However, they have since come back to me and said that the problem has returned.

I've researched output buffering problems, but there is 0KB in the output buffer. I've researched PHP memory limits, but I'm not getting the classic fatal error that would indicate this is an issue. After all, the page loads somewhat, but doesn't fully load.

Has anyone else run into a similar issue with PHP? I'm really banging my head against the wall trying to figure out what is going on, but I can't seem to find anything related in google searches.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So first, this question is not appropriate for Super User. Maybe Stack Overflow? But you need to show more code. That said you say “You can see some examples of the problem in the following screenshots…” But I have no idea what it *should* look like. To me this all seems fine. What is wrong? Perhaps this is all a CSS issue?

Comment: I tried to ask my question on Stack Overflow and the site sent me here... While looking at the screenshot, you will notice that there are certain table cells at the bottom of the image that do not render. This is where the script stops loading in the browser. There should be much more of the file that is loaded. I'll add additional screenshots to show the difference. Sorry about that!

Comment: Could be a PHP memory issue on the server? Or maybe even a CSS issue?

Comment: I don't think CSS is the problem because that would just cause formatting issues, and not prevent the rest of the PHP script from displaying altogether (correct?). I also performed a bunch of memory tests and well and things look good on that front. It looks like replacing the hundreds of echo statements that are display HTML with actual HTML and then only outputting the PHP variables with printf fixes the issue. But, I don't (at all) understand why that is.

Comment: @JakeGould Actually, with regard to styling, I have a ton of <td> elements on the page that use the align='center' property like this <td align='center'>. If I have my doctype declared using <!DOCTYPE html> (i.e. HTML 5), and the align parameter is deprecated in HTML 5, could that randomly cause my PHP script to stop rendering on the page?

Answer (score -1):

If your script is not terminating due to some error (which you can capture in your error log), the problem probably lies because of buffering (since you said the script is huge, it may be timing out).

Since you are accessing it locally, maybe you can't replicate it, but your users are using slower connections, and that's why they may be having the issue.

What I would recommend is to flush the buffer earlier, and at regular intervals, while your script runs (say every X number of records), or after each table group.

```
flush(); 
ob_flush();
```

Sometimes, you need to also send a header for it to work properly. If so, try adding the following as the first line of your script, and/or before any content is sent to the browser:

```
header('Content-Encoding: none;');
```

Ultimately, you may want to also work on the performance of your page, in order to load data quicker, and thus, avoiding any timeout related problems.

Comment: While this is a well written answer, how are you making all of these assumptions based only on reports of behavior and not the code itself?

Comment: Buffering is not the issue. I ran a ton of buffering tests, both locally and on the dev server, and it's completely empty. I did enhance performance by removing the echos that display HTML and replacing them with actual HTML and then only outputting the PHP variables with printf. That seems to help actually, but it doesn't exactly tell me why the echos are a problem in the first place.

Comment: What do you mean buffering is empty? You set output_buffering to zero (0)? You are already pushing the output buffer? How long does it take for your page to load?

Comment: Another thing that could be the culprit is memory. When your PHP runs out of memory, most of the time, it doesn't display an actual error (this has happened to me many times). What you could do is monitor your memory consumption during the scripts' execution with the PHP command: memory_get_usage()/1000000;

Comment: I mean that output buffering is not the issue because it is off. I also read that even if the output buffer limit is exceeded, then the data in the buffer will be displayed, the buffer will be flushed, and the output buffering will be turned off. Is that correct?

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of your page's header response? In Firefox, you press F12, go to the network tab, reload your page, and look for the Header Response data under the network tab.